# LaTeX : undefined control sequence while using outline package

Tags: undefined, control

I am getting this error in LaTeX while using the outline package.

> line 7 Undefined control sequence. \item
>   line 7: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item
>   line 7: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item
>   line 7: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \item

Here is the original code.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{outline} 
% [outline] includes new outline environment. I. A. 1. a. (1) (a) % use \begin{outline} \item ... \end{outline} 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Introduction}
\begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Applications} \\ Motivation for research and applications related to the subject. 
\item {\bf Organization} \\ Explain organization of the report, what is included, and what is not. 
\end{outline} 
\item {\bf Literature Survey } 
\begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Experimental Work }
\\ Literature describing experiments with something in common with my experiment. My experiment is subdivided into section relating to each aspect of the whole. 
\begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Drop Delivery } 
\\ Literature relating to the production of droplets. 
\begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Continuous } \\ Continuous drop production methods, i.e. jet methods. 
\item {\bf Drop on Demand } \\ Drop on demand methods, i.e. ink jet devices. Produce drops whenever needed, simplifies control of frequency. 
\item {\bf Flexibility } \\ Best methods in terms of flexible velocities, volumes, and frequencies. 
\item {\bf Control Circuitry } \\ Circuitry necessary to control the drops, may include 
control of generation, size, and frequency. Divertors and drop chargers.
\item {\bf Extensibility } \\ Methods extensible to 2D applications. \item {\bf Recirculation } \\ 
Recirculation techniques, pump, none, capillary. 
\end{outline} \item {\bf Instrumentation } \\ 
Literature dealing with measurement of various parameters. 
\begin{outline} \item {\bf Temperature } \begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Heater Surface } \item {\bf Fluid Temperature } \item {\bf Heat Flux } \item {\bf Heat Transfer Coefficient } 
\end{outline} \item {\bf Drop Characteristics } \begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Size } \item {\bf Velocity } \item {\bf Frequency } 
\end{outline} \end{outline} \item {\bf Heating Element } \\ 
Literature dealing with the heating element. Material properties, surface properties, heat sources. 
\begin{outline} \item {\bf Material } \item {\bf Heat Source } 
\end{outline} \end{outline} \item {\bf Analytical Work } \begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Evaporation } \item {\bf Boiling } \item {\bf Leidenfrost Temperatures } \item {\bf Heat Transfer } \item {\bf Numerical Analysis } \begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Drop Characteristics } \item {\bf Surface Wetting } \item {\bf Transient Temperatures } 
\end{outline} 
\end{outline} \end{outline} \item {\bf Proposed Research } \begin{outline} 
\item {\bf Experimental Work } \item {\bf Analytical Work } \end{outline} \end{outline} 
\end{document}
```

Whats interesting is that it compiled fine on Overleaf. I have double checked that I have all the necessary packages through the package manager.

Comment: It typesets on my laptop.

Comment: Oh thats weird. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am on MikTex 2.9 with Tex Studio and its compiling other documents fine.

Comment: What typeset engine did you use? I used XeLaTeX.

Comment: I did pdfLaTeX but i'll just tried XeLaTeX gives the same error.

Comment: On my TeXLive 2018 both `xelatex` and `pdflatex` run through without errors.

Comment: Could you check the .log file for the `outline` package version that is included? There seem to be two versions of `outline.sty` packaged with MiKTeX, one from the [`outline`](https://miktex.org/Package/Browse/outline) and one from the [`fundus-outline`](https://miktex.org/Package/Browse/fundus-outline) package. If I try to build your example on MiKTeX, it tries to install the latter version which is the wrong one. This package [doesn't seem to be included in TeX Live](https://ctan.org/pkg/fundus-outline), so the error doesn't occur there.

Comment: Yes the correct one is installed. Is there a way to check whether the package is loaded in correctly once you compile? The error seems to initiate at the \item which is supposed to be built into the package. I guess one more reason to look into TexLive.

Comment: I think it might be some conflicts in MikTex outline package with some other package. I just moved to outlines package to achieve a similar output (albiet with a 4 level enumerate structure vs 6 level) to achieve the desire goal.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://v1.overleaf.com/read/bqvqwygyvhwt Voting to close as unclear.